# duplicate question review management

Tags: bug, review, hyperlinks

When you click on the close button on a question and select `duplicate` you can then search for a question and get a result list. If you select a question that is on hold/closed for being a duplicate you can then click that linked question (the question it was a duplicate of) and it opens.

The problem I have is when you first click on the search results it opens in the small close window that you get, but when you click on the duplicate link it opens in a new window and takes you out of the close-question window. Which must be a bug.

Because at least I want to close to the question that is the "original" duplicate and the one that is open. So that the user easily can find the duplicate question and solve their problem.

Yes I know that I can copy the link and paste it into the close-window adress bar. But it shouldn't be that complicated to close a question.

The screenshot below shows the problem I described, if you click on the link below it will open the link as a normal link instead of the close-window. 
[image]

Comment: I know the question could be formulated better and shorter but I'm tired.

Comment: I think this is a feature request instead...

Comment: @Braiam or a bug of a current feature. Depends on how you see it.